# Add link icon that breaks with last word?

Tags: css

Is it possible add an icon after a link that breaks with the last word?

`:after` and `content` both break in Chrome.

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/V32Wd/1/

Comment: Check the syntax of your html. I can see a lot wrong with it.

Comment: These are just examples!

Comment: Doesn't matter. It will still affect how browsers display it.

Comment: Sorry but your comments are totally useless. These are just test links. Here is your proper html: `<a href="http://www.com">Link</a>`

Comment: You're asking a question on styling. If the syntax of the html is invalid, it will not be displayed in the browser correctly. Give us the html that you are actually going to use. Whats the point in invalid html just for testing purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the markup `<a class="after" href="#">The icon should not break alone</a>`, use the following CSS code:

```
a.after:after {
    content: '\feff' url('...');
    padding-left: 4px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The addition of `'\feff'` means adding U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE, an invisible control character that prevents line breaks before and after. This helps on Chrome and IE, but not on Firefox. Adding `white-space: nowrap` deals with the issue on Firefox; this is illogical since by definition it only prevents line breaks inside the pseudo-element, and the issue is a line break between the normal content and the pseudo-element—anyway, since it helps, let’s use it here.

A more common approach is to add an icon as a background image for the `a` element, placed at the right. This avoids the line breaking issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about U+FEFF. my link should have an icon on the right and two on the left, so `background`is used already. I also just discovered setting multiple background-images via CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

For those of us who are not lucky to have font icons available and must use background SVG's, and cannot split the URL, it gets a bit more complicated...

At first I wanted to do it by finding the last word in the URL, taking it out, putting it in its own span and attach the icon to it, but then I realized our component accepts arbitrary HTML so I couldn't do that anymore unless I made it work only for string types.

So the best solution I could find so far, is to pretend that I have a font icon by using empty space characters in content, then setting SVG as background:

```scss
.link-icon-word-break {
  &::after {
    content: '\00A0\00A0\00A0\00A0';
    background-image: url('/path/image.svg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1rem 1rem;
    margin-left: 0.25rem;
    margin-right: 0.25rem;
    vertical-align: -0.125rem;
  }
}
```

The obvious downside here is that we must ensure that the number of whitespace characters in content is enough so that the icon shows up right. If there's too many, there will be a lot of space, and if there's too few, it will clip.