# Make link icon break with last word

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add link icon that breaks with last word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780461/add-link-icon-that-breaks-with-last-word)

When text is too long for a container I would like to break the last word onto a new line rather then just the background image that appears after it.

Here is an iamge of the issue:[image: Text not breaking with the background-image.]

I would like the word "too." to break to the next line along with the background-image.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="myIcon">The name of some link goes here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="myIcon">The name of some link goes here too.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="myIcon">Here is yet another link that could be used</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="myIcon">This could be a really long link that one could try to use also</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The name of some link goes here.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The name of some link goes here.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The name of some link goes here.</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.myIcon:after {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    content:'';
    background-image: url("/wps/themes/html/3M.com/images/ui-icons_000000_256x240.png");
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jukka.  I think my question is a duplicate.  I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think to ensure that this works across browsers you will have to wrap the last word in a span and then apply the icon to the span.

```
<li><a href="#">This could be a really long link that one could try to use <span class="myIcon">also</span></a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.myIcon {
    display:inline-block;
    background: url("/wps/themes/html/3M.com/images/ui-icons_000000_256x240.png") no-repeat center right;
    padding-right:16px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

[Example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/KU6P9/)

Comment: Thanks!  I hate having to wrap an additional span around the word but you are right about having it work for older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a break-word in your css, which would automatically force your text to wrap after a certain length:

```
.myIcon:after {
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
content:'';
background-image: url("/wps/themes/html/3M.com/images/ui-icons_000000_256x240.png");
vertical-align:middle;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```